# when using import statement i get "OSError: [WinError 193] %1 n�est pas une application Win32 valide" error

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I'm trying to use python on the sublime text 3 code editor. It works well except for one thing, when I try to import a library like numpy, pandas or any library it will say something like this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\python project\1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "E:\Python\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

I don't understand what this means even after looking at 20 different internet pages.

I've got 2 questions:

1. Is there a way to allow the use of python libraries with sublime text and if so could you link me a tutorial please?
2. Should I just give up on sublime text and try to find an IDE that is more straightforward? ( I keep trying to search for an ide but every single time I don't even understand how to boot them. I'm currently using pyzo and it's functionning much better than anything else I've tried)

Here is what the code look like:

```
import numpy
```

Comment: I would suggest you to download and install [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/download). After installing VSCode, install python plugin for VSCode. It has features that allows you to auto-complete library names and methods.

Comment: try running the program from a command line/terminal

Comment: There's nothing special about using Python with Sublime Text; it just uses the installed `python` interpreter to run your program. So to `import numpy` you have to do what you would do in normal `python` to install the `numpy` library first. It may help to search for Python tutorials without focusing on the environment you're using (Sublime in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i found the issue it has nothing to do with sublime text 3. for some reasons the issue came from numpy. It might have to do with numpy version ( i switched from python 32bits to python 64bits, i updated numpy but i think i just got the updated 32bits version which python 64bits cannot use). I'm using windows so what i did is open the command promp, uninstall numpy and reinstall it. If anyone else struggles with this issue i'd suggest doing the same, uninstalling and reinstalling the concerned libraries.

Thank you guys for your answers.